# How do I create a tiff file in R under Linux/Unix?

Tags: r

How do I save a plot to a tiff file under Linux/Unix platform? I often do this under Windows with tiff(...). Also is there a way to compress the tiff file as in compression="lzw" under Windows?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use `tiff(...,compression="tiff")` under unix too, that's what I do -- perhaps you need `libtiff` (`libtiff4`?) installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If capabilities("tiff") is TRUE then you can use the tiff function or dev.copy(tiff) to make a tiff from an existing plot.

If capabilities("tiff") is FALSE then you need to reinstall R. Most binary R distributions should have it, if you've compiled it yourself you need to make sure you have the libtiff development stuff installed first.

tiff(file="foo.tiff",compression="lzw") should do lzw compression, but again its dependent on having the correct libraries and headers for compiling compression into your tiff library.

Answer (score 1):

Try `CairoTIFF` in the [`Cairo`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html) package.